# How dose the client securely sends secert to server before encrypted transmission starts during SSL handshake in HTTPS connection

Tags: ssl, https

I'm recently reading the Secure HTTP chapter of the book *HTTP The Definitive Guide*. In the chapter it talks about how an encrypted connection is created for HTTPS and there is a diagram for the SSL handshake as shown below
[image]

My question is that client and server starts sending encrypted message in step 4, but in step 3, how do they send the secret securely. If the secret get's intercepted by someone, it will be stolen because it's not encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description you quote is **mostly obsolete**. It is for the original form of keyexchange created in early SSL (v2, then v3) and carried forward for a while in TLS, called simply 'RSA' keyexchange or sometimes emphasized as 'plain RSA' or 'RSA-only'.

> [the secret] will be stolen because it's not encrypted.

It *is* encrypted using the server's RSA public key (from the server's certificate), using the first freely-published standard for RSA encryption, namely v1 of [PKCS1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) (Public Key Cryptography Standard #1) from what was then the 'Labs' subsidiary of the company founded by the inventors of RSA. For the most recent specification, see [rfc5246 section 7.4.7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.7.1) (not duplicated here because it's three pages).
As described there, in the years since PKCS1v1.5 encryption was chosen, attacks against it have been discovered and gradually improved, reducing its safety and adding to the impetus to replace it (below).

However, SSLv3 added (back in the Bill Clinton era) and TLS retained and improved *better* keyexchange methods using [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) in 'ephemeral' mode, abbreviated DHE, and later a mathematically advanced variant Elliptic-Curve Diffie-Hellman, (either of) which provides [**forward secrecy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) (sometimes emphasized as *perfect forward secrecy*), combined with RSA, DSA, or ECDSA authentication (signature). For years security experts advised people to use these improved methods and were mostly ignored until Snowden made the whole world aware of mass surveillance operations; over the last 6 years people have moved almost entirely to DHE-based keyexchange, and the most recent version, TLS 1.3 published in 2018 and now implemented in a significant fraction of uses but not yet most, *requires* DHE and no longer supports plain-RSA keyexchange at all. 1.3 also rearranges parts of the protocol so that the simplified description you have isn't really correct at all, although it accomplishes the same result.

Comment: What a nice history class!

Comment: thanks very much, but, you don't explain where is the difference. is the beggining of handshake still vunerable or not?

Comment: @danilo 'vulnerable' could cover a huge range of possibilities; the Q was only about an attacker getting the shared secret (and thus being able to decrypt and/or alter data). If you use obsolete plain-RSA the secret is encrypted and thus safe. If you use either variant of Diffie-Hellman the secret is never sent and thus safe; this is explained in the wikipedia page I linked (as well as millions of other places you could find by searching for Diffie-Hellman).